# How to give feedback on audit reviews

Tags: feature-request, disputed-review-audits

Earlier today I failed a LQP audit review of an "answer" to this q

[How to batch create icon webfonts in windows from SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287670/how-to-batch-create-icon-webfonts-in-windows-from-svg-files)

Notice that it has an accepted one-liner answer referring the OP to a linked site.

The "answer" I was presented with in the review was another one-liner, allegedly by a user with a rep of 1, also containing a link, which was to

```
http://fontello.com/
```

I clicked "Edit" on the "answer" to check amongst other things that the linked address looked genuine.  It seemed to be, so I cancelled the edit and clicked on the link in the "answer" and that sent FF (v.33.0.2) off to fontello.com; admittedly FF then reported that a script has stopped working, and so I cancelled that and went back to the "answer".  It looked to me that it was 
just a new user trying to chip in with what was intended to be a helpful supplementary answer, so I decided to give it that benefit of the doubt and clicked "Looks OK".

So, by the time I was chided - unjustifiably imo - by "Stop & listen", I'd actually spent about 5 minutes on this "answer", including the time waiting for FF to conclude that a script has hung, so it wasn't at all a case of my just clicking on it without brain or attention engaged.

What is all the more galling about this is the contents of the message accompanying 'Stop & listen'.

> This post has severe quality issues. [...]

Well, it is no lower quality than the accepted answer to the q on which is is based.

> It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable [...]

Well, it certainly didn't contain any abuse or nonsense, nor did it seem to any of those others.

> readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful [...]

What on earth could be offensive or repulsive about a link to a site which distributes fonts?

Anyway, it seems to me that the "Audit review" was actually of a lot lower quality than the bait is was using.

I realise of course that the art of constructing suitable "bait" for audit reviews must be an imperfect one, but what I'd like to know is why isn't there a mechanism for flagging up audit review material which is clearly nonsense? Without such a facility, what's the point of donating one's time to the review queues at all?

(Btw, although what I've been describing seems like a bug to me, I haven't used the "Bug" tag because the description of that includes "reproducible", but I've no idea how to reproduce what I encountered, nor give a recipe for another to reproduce it)

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)